# Google Cloud SQL Server Unknown Error/Invalid Argument

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, database-backups, database-restore

I'm getting an Unknown Error when trying to import a `.bak` file into a Google Cloud SQL Server instance. It's using SQL Server 2017 Web and it's taken from a SQL Server 2017 Web Linux machine. The database has compatibility level 100.

The command I am using is (names replaced for obscurity)

```
gcloud sql import bak %servername% gs://%bucketname%/%dbname%.bak --database=%dbname%--verbosity debug
```

The errors it throws are:

> Importing data into Cloud SQL instance...failed.
> DEBUG: (gcloud.sql.import.bak) [INVALID_ARGUMENT]
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 983, in Execute
> resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
>
> File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line
> 808, in Run
> resources = command_instance.Run(args)
>
> File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/sql/import/bak.py", line 87, in Run
> return import_util.RunBakImportCommand(args, client)
>
> File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/sql/import_util.py", line 173, in RunBakImportCommand
> return RunImportCommand(args, client, sql_import_context)
>
> File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/sql/import_util.py", line 111, in RunImportCommand
> sql_client, operation_ref, 'Importing data into Cloud SQL instance')
>
> File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/sql/operations.py", line 100, in WaitForOperation
> sleep_ms=_BaseOperations._INITIAL_SLEEP_MS)
>
> File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/retry.py", line 229, in RetryOnResult
> if not should_retry(result, state):
>
> File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/sql/operations.py", line 80, in ShouldRetryFunc
> raise result

> googlecloudsdk.api_lib.sql.exceptions.OperationError: [INVALID_ARGUMENT]
> ERROR: (gcloud.sql.import.bak) [INVALID_ARGUMENT]

I've tried remaking backup, putting into different buckets, giving full storage admin rights to service account of cloud sql but it just doesn't seem to want to play ball and is not giving a very helpful error.

Importing through the GUI also results in an unknown error appearing in the event log.

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this error?  Or an alternative database backup/restore method to get a db from SQL Server to cloud sql?

Thanks in advance

Richard

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was the version of SQL.  Backup source was 2019.  Trying to restore to 2017.  Had to downgrade source to 2017 to get it to work.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue. I have 13 backup files from Azure SQL Database, compatibility mode 150. I'm trying to restore them on a Cloud SQL, SQL Server 2019, also compatibility mode 150. In 2 of 13, coincidentally the largest files, I get the errors described here. The only difference from your case is that my files are "sql" instead of "bak".

Answer (score 0):

According to the [public docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/import-export/importing), you should be using the '**gcloud beta**' command, not the regular 'gcloud' as it does not have the 'bak' argument.

```
gcloud beta sql import bak [INSTANCE_NAME] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[FILE_NAME] \
                        --database=[DATABASE_NAME]
```